# Как сделать чтобы выводилась индивидуальная информация о каждом продукте

Tags: javascript, php, html

У меня есть такой код

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="project">
        <div class="title">Проект 1</div>
        <div class="opis">Описание 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="project">
        <div class="title">Проект 2</div>
        <div class="opis">Описание 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="project">
        <div class="title">Проект 3</div>
        <div class="opis">Описание 3</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

И я хочу чтобы при нажатии на один из проектов был редирект на страницу index2.php где бы выводилась название и описание того проекта , на который я нажал.

Comment: А где вы храните информацию которую нужно выводить?... Если у вас буквально пара-тройка проектов то можете просто html файлы создать с тексом, в противном случае надо по-другому вывод делать

Answer (score 0):

Если Вы знаете PHP на минимальном уровне, проблем для Вас это не должно было бы составить.
Для каждого проекта делаете ссылку () и в ней указываете href=index2.php?title=ProjectTitle&description=ProjectDescription.

В файле index2.php считываете значения с ссылки, а именно title & description, а после выводите на странице с помощью echo.

Надеюсь Вам поможет эта информация. Можете также погуглить "Как получить данные с ссылки PHP".